# How to make .htaccess RewriteRule that support path and query_string at the same time

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need help with .htaccess on RewriteRule. I already have some URL that are using the RewriteRule like:

`https://example.com/content/2/about_us`

This URL above, I can successfully redirect to page.php and capture variable like id=2 and pagename=about_us

But there are URL that I would like to have the format about and normal query_string at the same time like the following:

`https://example.com/page?keyword=battery&sort=asc&pagenum=1`

This URL above would redirect to page.php and I want to capture the query_string. Those query_string would not limit to keyword, sort, pagenum. It can be any other name. At the moment I cannot capture the query_string at all.

At the moment I can only redirect the URL `https://example.com/page` to page.php with the following:

```
RewriteRule ^page/?$ page.php [L]
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: Could you please confirm what link you are hitting in browser and what link you want it to become? Thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 This is the link in browser https://example.com/page?keyword=battery&sort=asc&pagenum=1. It does not need to be rewritten to any other format, just that I need to be able to extract the query_string at the back.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 What I wanted to achive is a combination of both type in my example about. A normal rewrite for this https://example.com/content/2/about_us plus extra query_string which can be https://example.com/content/2/about_us?tag=battery&sort=asc

Comment: The existing query string should automatically get appended, until you explicitly did anything against that. Perhaps you have more rewriting configured, that interferes with this somehow? If so, show us the full thing.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following .htaccess rules file.

***Please make sure:***

- Place your .htaccess rules file along with `content` folder.
- Clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON

RewriteBase /content/2/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(content/2)/([^/]*)/?$ $1/$2.php?tag=battery&sort=asc [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Base on the last line if I place the (content/2)/(about_us) inside, then it would be a static url. Infact the URL could be https://example.com/content/2/about_us or .../content/14/list, etc...etc.. 

So the URL is quite dynamic as follow: https://example.com/content/<dynamic_id>/<dynamic_name>?<dynamic_query_string_name_and_value>

Comment: @EdisonWong, ok sure, I have edited my rules once and let me know how it goes, cheers.

Comment: @EdisonWong, Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

Comment: @EdisonWong, Also your .php files should be present in `content/2` folder, adding an additional note here.

Comment: for this line 
RewriteRule ^(content/2)/([^/]*)/?$ $1/$2.php?tag=battery&sort=asc [NC,QSA,L]  

if I change it to RewriteRule ^(content)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ $1/$2.php?tag=battery&sort=asc [NC,QSA,L]

would the (content) in this redirect to page.php? 
What about the query_string? If I have "keyword" instead of "tag" or maybe "price" depending on what user what to use from the page would that work also, or do I need to define each possible query_string in the .htaccess?

Comment: @EdisonWong, if you have to set query string as per your URI/URL `Eg:` have query string `abc?=def` for `http:localhost:8000/singh` AND have `rty?=ert` for `http://localhost:8000/blabla` then yes you have to set separate rules for separate conditions/URLs. Let me know, cheers.

Comment: @EdisonWong, kindly do let me know if this has helped you, cheers 

Comment: Base on your solution I would seem to stuck with 2 defined parameter which is tag and sort. I am looking for ways to make it so that the parameter name would be dynamic also